# How to merge audio and video from different sources for kinesis video

Tags: gstreamer, amazon-kinesis, gstreamer-1.0

How do I put unrelated audio into any generated video stream in a way that keeps them in sync in gstreamer?

Context:

I want to stream audio from icecast into a Kinesis Video stream, and then view it with Amazon's player. The player only works if there is video as well as audio, so I generate video with testvideosrc.

The video and audio need to be in sync in terms of timestamps, or the Kinesis sink 'kvssink' throws an error. But because they are two separate sources, they are not in sink.

I am using gst-launch-1.0 to run my pipeline.

My basic attempt was like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
    videotestsrc pattern=red ! video/x-raw,framerate=25/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc,alignment=au !  \
    queue ! kvssink name=sink stream-name="NAME" access-key="KEY" secret-key="S_KEY" \
    uridecodebin uri=http://ice-the.musicradio.com/LBCLondon ! audioconvert ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! queue ! sink.
```

The error message I get translates to:
STATUS_MAX_FRAME_TIMESTAMP_DELTA_BETWEEN_TRACKS_EXCEEDED

This indicates that the audio and video timestamps are too different, so I want to force them to match, maybe by throwing away the video timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

There are different meanings of "sync". Let us ignore lip sync for a moment (where audio and video match to each other).

There is sync in terms of timestamps - e.g. do they carry similar timestamps in their representation. And sync in terms of when in real time do these samples with timestamps actually arrive at the sink (latency).

Hard to tell by the error which one exactly the sink is complaining about.

Maybe try `x264enc tune=zerolatency` for a start, as without that options the encoder produces a two second latency which may cause issues for certain requirements.

Then again the audio stream will have some latency too. It may not be easy to tune these two to match. The sink should actually do the buffering ans synchronization.

Comment: >> The sink should actually do the buffering ans synchronization.
This may be key - perhaps this particular sink does not do this well. 
It appears it tolerates a 60 frame (~2 second) lag though.